# What does ^ in a regex mean?

Tags: regex

I am quite confused as I thought that ^ in regular expressions negated the sequence, however this:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z ]+$
```

works vice versa.  nothing other than numbers, letters and space is allowed. I do not understand it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `^` invertes a character choice only when it is *inside* of the `[]`. Here, it matches the beginning of the string, while `$` matches the end.

Therefore, this regexp matches any string that consists *solely* of the given characters (instead of just containing them "somewhere").

This may or may not make a difference, depending on whether you "match" the regexp or "search" for it. ("matching" can be seen as an implicit `^` and `$` anchoring of the regular expression.)

Answer (score 2):

It does not negate a sequence, it negates a character class, if it is the **first** character inside such a class, e.g. `[^0-9a-zA-Z ]` would be a negated character class that matches any character but those inside the class.

If the `^` is outside a character class it is an anchor for the start of the string and `$` is an anchor for the end of the string (or the start/end of a row with multiline option)

See here on [regular-expression.info for more information about anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

Comment: +1 stress on it needing to be the _first_ character in the character class

Answer (score 1):

^ means "string starts with the pattern" and $ means "string ends with pattern".

So this pattern would allow any strings consisting of numbers, letters and spaces that has at least length 1 (because of the +).